# How can we compute the symbolic determinant and permanent in SymPy?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, python, programming, geometric-complexity

I'm not finding the answer to this simply by googling, so I think it has a place on this site, seeing as all the online symbolic determinant calculators don't seem to work right, and so forget about computing the symbolic permanent.  By symbolic, I mean in terms of variable $A_{ij}$'s all $n^2$ of them.

What I would like to do is compute the determinant & the permanent for small test cases i.e. for $n \times n$ matrices of SymPy symbols named either via subscript numbering or using up the Latin / Greek letters, for $n \lt 20$.

I'm using this in my research of elementary approaches to [computing the permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent).

I would then like to take the formula and display it either at run-time or via copy / paste in rendered LaTeX, so please keep that in mind, i.e. multiplication should just be juxtaposition.

Do you know how to do this?  Thank you.

This is of value to undergraduate researchers who'd like to mess around with computing the permanent.

Comment: What do you mean "all the online symbolic determinant calculators don't seem to work right"? Wolfram Alpha for example is able to compute symbolic determinants.

Comment: @blargoner I tried Wolfram alpha using {{}} or nested braces for matrix rep, and it came up with "can't compute this" or simply did not compute it.  The one where you enter in entries one-by-one also did not work, so if you could link me to a result page, that would be great.  But note, I'm also asking for computation of the permanent.  For which I would bet their is no online calculator for because it's not very common.  Also, SymPy's documentation hasn't made it very straightforward how to compute the permanent.  Surely, someone on this site knows the answer to this question.

Comment: @blargoner and I'm not saying "do the code for me".  This is merely 10-20 lines of code, from which I will expand into my own code.  I also have written a lot of code for this site, mostly in my own questions, but I don't practice hiding the code from any of you all.  So I would expect some coding help in return.   I don't want to spend years learning SymPy, I'm a very sparse user of it.  It is simply a tool for me, and I use it in certain cases where repetitive hand computations get too tiresome.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Det%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D) is a simple $2\times 2$ determinant calculation. While the Wolfram Language has an [implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permanent.html) of the permanent function, it may not work on Alpha.

Comment: I think what you'd hate even more is if I re-invented the wheel and wrote my own permanent function.

Comment: @blargoner okay, that shows me how to use their interface properly, what I was doing wrong was probably just using vertical bars.  However, there is still some value in having this done in SymPy so that we can (those who are interested) experiment with different formulas.  Hand-entering into Wolfram Alpha, is between pen & paper and coding.  The code method will be of best utility for us mathematicians.

Comment: If no one makes an answer, I will end up, though struggling for longer than necessary, come up with the canonical example, and I will make an answer here myself.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical code for doing the above is this.  I've also included how to assign to the individual matrix entries, because to experiment with the permanent, you'll have to be able to do that:

```
from sympy import *
from itertools import permutations
from functools import reduce
# init_printing()   # Used for outputing LaTeX if needed later

n = 4

A = MatrixSymbol('A', n, n)
A = Matrix(A)

detA = A.det()

pprint(detA)

# permA = A.per()  # Fails with some internal library erorr that 'Integer' object is not iterable

def permanent(A:Matrix):
    n = len(A.row(0))
    assert n == len(A.col(0))
    Sn = permutations(range(n))
    formula = 0
    mul = lambda x,y: x*y
    for sigma in Sn:
        formula += reduce(mul, [A[i, sigma[i]] for i in range(n)])
    return formula

permA = permanent(A)
pprint(permA)

# Example matrix entry assignment:

A[0,0] = -A[0,0]

pprint(A)
```

It was not as bad as I expected.  I made use mainly of the SymPy documentation.